# Pseudorandom number generation predictability

Tags: random-number-generator

Can you expect with certainty that any pseudo-random number generator will produce the same stream with a shared seed?

Comment: Can you point any definition of _pseudo_ random generator that even remotely suggests otherwise? Or are you considering divergent implementations due to errors or incomplete specifications, incorrect use, defective hardware, cosmic rays, miracles?

Comment: @fgrieu How can it be that every implementation of a PRNG produces the same output? Can you recommend academic sources explaining?

Comment: If two different implementations generate different streams given the same seed, they're not the same PRNG (they may be ones with equivalent security, but not the same one)

Comment: There have supposedly been cases where people have reverse-engineered the PRNG's used in casino slot machines, to predict when these machines will payout.  See https://www.wired.com/story/meet-alex-the-russian-casino-hacker-who-makes-millions-targeting-slot-machines/

Comment: @DanielAwbrey In reverse, can you name any algorithm that generates different output for the same input? PRNG's are just that, mathematical algorithms. Like almost all algorithms in computers (or otherwise), they are entirely deterministic. Actually, it is quite wonderful that they can produce a unpredictable stream given an unpredictable seed.

Comment: @DanielAwbrey: What exactly you mean by **any**? Do mean different (physical) generator instances implementing **the same algorithm**, like 2 identical computers running identical software? In such case the output **must** be the same for the same input. Or do you mean 2 instances implementing **different algorithms**? Then you cannot expect the same output.

Comment: @mentallurg Intuitively that makes sense that the same algorithm would produce the same output because computers are deterministic. However, all programming languages must have divergent implementations of a PRNG's, correct?

Comment: @DanielAwbrey: We don't expect that every CPU has the same performance, the same size, the same temperature etc. Even the supported instruction set can be slightly different in different CPU. Why should we expect that *all* CPUs implement the same algorithm for generation of random numbers? Intel has one algorithm, AMD has other. And even across different generations or series of the same company it can be slightly different...

Comment: @DanielAwbrey: ... Why different? Because the requirements constantly change: generators are expected to provide more numbers, or generators are expected to use om,re entropy, or some bugs or potential weaknesses found and need to fixed, etc. It is natural, that algorithms of hardware generators change over the time.

Comment: @DanielAwbrey: Besides hardware, there are generators on the OS level, like /dev/urandom on Linux. And what generators uses particular software platform like Java or C# is up to them. E.g. Java on Linux has generator that is based on Linux /dev/urandom. But we cannot say that all software platforms use different algorithms. There is just no reason to expect that they are the same. So your statement *all programming languages must have divergent implementations* is not true.

Comment: "We don't expect that every CPU has the same performance, the same size, the same temperature etc. Even the supported instruction set can be slightly different in different CPU. Why should we expect that all CPUs implement the same algorithm for generation of random numbers?"; well , we generally expect that if two different CPUs both add the numbers 2 and 2, they both come up with the same answer (even if they differ in performance, instruction set, etc).  What a RNG is a something more complicated algorithm than addition (but nonetheless a fixed algorithm)

Answer (score 4):

Take (hypothetical) seeded deterministic PRNG algorithm `Gen1`. If you use `Gen1` to produce a stream, and I use `Gen1` with the same seed, I will get an identical stream. As per [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), a PRNG is deterministic.

Now consider another hypothetical seeded deterministic PRNG `Gen2`, which uses a different algorithm than `Gen1`. If I use `Gen2` with the same seed as before, there is no reason to expect the same stream to result.